# Source of Credit Card Payment as it relates to building credit

Tags: credit-card

Does it matter as far as building credit if a student credit card bill is paid from the parents' checking account?

Answer (score 6):

The credit card company only cares that the money gets there on time. If it does they report good things, if it is late or less than the minimum they report bad things.

If the information needed to transfer the funds is correct they will credit the account. If the check has the account number in the memo line the account will be credited. If the parents transfer funds into a students checking account, and then the money is transferred to the credit card company, then nobody will know...or care.

That last example is how I did it with my college age kids. Money for books and other required items was transferred to their checking account, and then they paid the credit card bill.

Comment: Just to emphasise that is often not possible for a third party to pay the credit card bill directly, for all the usual money laundering etc. reasons. It needs to be paid into a checking account in the name of the credit card holder, and from there to the credit card account.

Comment: @jcaron that's not true at all.

Comment: @quid It depends on the jurisdiction and the credit card, but it is definitely the case in many situations. Can't find the relevant language right now, but I'm 100% certain I've seen it for at least one card.

Comment: Your comment doesn't say "sometimes it matters depending on the jurisdiction."  If you send a check or money order to the appropriate address with the account number noted, the bill gets paid in almost every situation.  If you think the exception you've bumped in to is worth emphasizing you should write an answer.